# can't render react component which takes another component as a prop in playwright

Tags: reactjs, playwright, playwright-test

I've got a React component which takes another component as a prop, and I'm getting an error when I try to render this in Playwright. Here's a simplified example:

```
// in MyComponent.jsx

export const MyComponent = ({ SubComponent }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <SubComponent />
    </div>
  );
};
```

```
// in MyComponent.playwright.spec.js

import { expect, test } from '@playwright/experimental-ct-react';
import { MyComponent } from './MyComponent';

const TestSubComponent = () => <p>Hello</p>;

test.describe('My Component', () => {
  test('it should render', async ({ mount, page }) => {
    const component = await mount(
      <MyComponent SubComponent={TestSubComponent} />
    );
    await expect(component).toContainText('Hello');
  });
});
```

My expectation is that this test should pass as it should render the `SubComponent` inside `MyComponent`. But what happens is that it fails with an error:

```
    undefined: Error: Minified React error #152; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=152&args[]=Component for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.

       6 | test.describe('My Component', () => {
       7 |   test('it should render', async ({ mount, page }) => {
    >  8 |     const component = await mount(
         |                             ^
       9 |       <MyComponent SubComponent={TestSubComponent} />
      10 |     );
      11 |     await expect(component).toContainText('Hello');
```

The React error is minified so it's hard to tell what's gone wrong.

What's the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug. Issue raised on GitHub here: https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/15620